Fixing Slow Boot in Ubuntu 24.10: Disabling the TPM Module
24.10 running on my Dell Inspiron 15 has a 90 second boot delay because the BIOS doesn't support tpm2.0. Which grub file can I edit, and what to add to stop loading the tpm module?

Adding tpm_tis.interrupts=0 to GRUB options didn't seem to change anything, but this did the trick for me:
sudo systemctl mask tpm2.target

Then reboot. Tested on Ubuntu 24.10.

You can edit the GRUB configuration file to disable TPM, stop the TPM module from loading at boot, and potentially resolve the boot delay. Here’s how to do it on your Dell Inspiron 15 running Ubuntu 24.10:
Steps to Disable TPM via GRUB:

1: Open the GRUB configuration file for editing:
sudo nano /etc/default/grub


2: Add the parameter to disable TPM: Look for the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. This line contains the default kernel parameters passed during boot. You’ll add the `tpm_tis.interrupts=0` parameter to disable TPM.

For example, modify it to look like this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash tpm_tis.interrupts=0"


3: Save and exit the editor:
Press CTRL + X to exit, then Y to confirm changes, and press Enter to save.

4: Update GRUB to apply the changes:
sudo update-grub


5: Reboot your system:

sudo reboot

This process should stop the TPM module from loading, which may help reduce or eliminate the boot delay caused by the unsupported TPM module on your system. If you still experience issues, you can also try disabling TPM in the BIOS settings directly, if that option is available.

I added tpm_tis.interrupts=0 to the grub file, but boot was still slow. Then I also disabled tpm in bios and that solved the issue. Thanks

I'm also facing this issue.
I originally clean-installed 24.04 with ZFS Encryption option (because this encryption method seems to run faster with my Samsung 850 EVO SATA SSD). Then I upgraded recently to 24.10 and I'm facing this slower boot. Not sure if it is encryption or ZFS related, mentioning just in case.
B450 Motherboard / 5800X3D CPU / RX 6800 GPU.

This isn't a solution for the problem at hand; it should be added as a comment instead.
